# Create CGContext for CoreText

Tags: ios, calayer, cgcontext, core-text

I was trying to render some CoreText in a CALayer, so that i can adjust the alpha of that layer explicitly.  I tried overriding the drawRect: method but that, as far as i know, only draws on the root layer of the view, and i have two sublayers, a bg image and the CoreText.  Here's the method that attempts to draw the CoreText layer: (which works in drawRect if i remove the createContext code)

```
-(void) drawTextLayer
{
    //get context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(250.0, 137.0), YES, 1.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//draw text
//attribute string
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:displayTxt];

//get font    
NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"idolwild"
                                                     ofType:@"ttf"];

CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)fontPath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL(url);
CGFontRef theCGFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider);
CTFontRef idolwild = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(theCGFont, 16.0, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, nil);

CFRelease(theCGFont);
CFRelease(dataProvider);
CFRelease(url);

[attrStr addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName
                value:(id)idolwild
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];


//create paragraph style and assign text alignment to it
CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTCenterTextAlignment;
CTParagraphStyleSetting _settings[] = {    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment} };
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(_settings, sizeof(_settings) / sizeof(_settings[0]));

//set paragraph style attribute
[attrStr addAttribute:(id)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName
                value:(id)paragraphStyle
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];


[attrStr addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                value:(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];


[attrStr addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                value:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [[wordRanges objectAtIndex:currentTextindex] intValue])];


//layout master
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrStr);

//bounding eclipse
CGMutablePathRef boundingEclipse = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(boundingEclipse, NULL, boundingEclipseRect);


//ctframe
CTFrameRef bubbleFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, 
                                                  CFRangeMake(0, 0),
                                                  boundingEclipse, NULL);

// flip the coordinate system
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);


    //fill bg to visual
    CGContextAddPath(context, boundingEclipse);
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillPath(context);

//draw
CTFrameDraw(bubbleFrame, context);

//add to layer
UIImage *tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
textLayer.contents = tempImage;

//cleanup
CGPathRelease(boundingEclipse);
CFRelease(framesetter);
CFRelease(bubbleFrame);
CFRelease(idolwild);
CGContextRelease(context);

[attrStr release];
}
```

--any theory on CALayers and CGContexts is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest three different methods:

1. Subclass `CALayer` and implement its `drawInContext:`.
2. Set an object that is not a `UIView` as the sublayer's `delegate`, then implement `drawLayer:inContext:`.
3. Create a `CGImage` and set it as the layer's contents:

   ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   /// draw

   UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   sublayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
   ```

Comment: i like suggestion #3. One question about the first two suggestion, the drawInContext: method, Does that draw the CALayer as an image into the Context, or does it draw the CALayer using the param context?